# Convert richtext strings to excel

Tags: excel, richtext

I have a form that has [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) for richtext formatting. All of our data is available to export as an HTML report, PDF Report, and Excel Spreadsheet (report).

The fields, that we allow richtext in, show up as the formatted values in both the HTML and PDF reports, but in Excel we show them as strings. For instance:
<b>this part is bold</b><br />line 2 here.

I need a way to make that show up as bold/line-break in excel rather then just showing that string, or at least a way to strip the HTML tags out of there and just show plain text (though I would really like to at least keep the line breaks). Is there some type of macro I can include in the excel download or some C++ program that can convert it or something?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar with [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home)

The trick is to take your formatted data and find a pattern.  In your case, it would probably be table rows/table cells.  Iterate through that structure setting the excel cell values as you go.  For complex formatting you could fairly simply regex replace what is necessary to get formatted as you desire.  The theory may sound a little complicated, but once you get down to it, it's only an hour or two's worth of work.

Certainly there are equivalent programs based on other server technologies.  But this one has worked brilliantly for me over the years, and I trust it to work on sites for very big clients with crazy inbound traffic numbers...and it's never failed.  It's the only reliable way I've found to write perfect, properly formatted Excel without requiring the user to jump through hoops to get a specific browser.